# Creating proxy server with OWIN

Tags: c#, owin, http-proxy

## The requirement

The organization have a proxy and it requires authentication.

A third party software supports proxy, but does not support proxy authentication.

So we want to write a small proxy program that delegates the requests from the third party software to the organization proxy.

(We use OWIN self hosting for this service. the project is a console application)

## The class ProxyHandler

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

...

public class ProxyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public static IWebProxy Proxy { get; set; }
    public ProxyHandler()
    {

    }
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage>
        SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage req, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var fwd = new UriBuilder(req.RequestUri);
        fwd.Port = 443; //The software uses https only; 
                        //in the test below this is not even called so does not matter

        req.RequestUri = fwd.Uri;

        var h = new HttpClientHandler();
        h.UseCookies = true;
        h.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        h.Proxy = Proxy;
        var c = new HttpClient(h);
        var resp = await c.SendAsync(req, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        return resp;
    }
}
```

## The class Startup

```
using Owin;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

...

class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder b)
    {
        var cfg = new HttpConfiguration();
        cfg.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "Proxy",
            "{*path}",
            new {path=RouteParameter.Optional},
            null,
            HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(
                new HttpClientHandler(),
                new DelegatingHandler[] { }
            ));
        b.UseWebApi(cfg);
    }
}
```

## The code that starts the proxy service and test with a download

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

...

        var p = new WebProxy(proxy_uri, true)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(domain_user, password)
        };
        ProxyHandler.Proxy = p;
        var app = WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:8181/");

        using (app)
        {
            var wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Proxy = new WebProxy("localhost:8181", true);

            var downloaded = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync
                (new Uri("http://example.com/));
            Console.WriteLine(downloaded);
        }
```

## The result

The call to `wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync` throws HTTP 400 error. The `SendAsync` method was not called at all.

## The question

How can I make it work?

Comment: So...how did it go?

Comment: This was 2 years ago, and I forgotten how we resolve this. If you have the same problem, let me know or you are free to ask a new question. NOTE: the code above was 2 years old, and now Rust supports async etc, so things might be quite different.

Comment: Oh sorry I thought it was Rust but it is C#. But still, things change.